# Installing the same app on two emulators

Tags: android, emulation

When I launch the android emulator through eclipse for the first time, its menu shows all the test apps that I have created. But when the launch a second instance of the same emulator, its menu does not shows any of my apps. How can I install my apps on the second emulator as well? I need to have an application installed on both the emulators to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you can't run two emulators simultaneously. In fact you can but second emulator will not use emulator image files - second emulator will not use previously saved data and will not save any changes. Two emulators can't use one emulator image file simultaneously. You can read about emulator image files [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#diskimages).

Solutions:
You can install your application on second emulator after launching through Eclipse or adb.
Or you can create another "emulator" (AVD file). [How to do it](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html#createavd).

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse you can run the app in the desired emulator. Just click the run button and choose the emulator you want to have it to run in. The apps are in the other emulator because you used that emulator apperently all the time. When you wipe user data at launch of the emulator all the apps are gone.

So just run it in the other emulator and it will be available from the menu.